# What are the health risks of having twins (or more)?

Tags: pregnancy

What are the health risks of being pregnant with twins, and how does it compare to being pregnant with just one child?

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing, the body will be carrying larger, and ache a whole lot more.
Pregnancy comes with its own risks and complications but having twins increases those risks significantly. With singleton pregnancy, one prenatal vitamin in a day is sufficient. But it needs more for an iron supplement and at least 1mg of folic acid for Twins. Those vitamin would reach to 16 cups of water requirements. [vitamin also included: 2,000 IU of Vitamin D, 1,000 mg of Calcium, for Twins] .

The body needs more water (16 cups) per day. It is really difficult but staying hydrated can stave off contractions and keep the body well hydrated.

Exercise isn't important but rest.
Yoga and stretching is okay but aerobic or strenuous activities are not good for Twin Pregnancies when it's good for singleton. Simple walk around 30 minutes everyday is should-do.

While singleton, sawing the Doctor once a month is great but Twin, every two-three weeks is necessary to monitor any changes and risks.

Please see

> Baby Websites

for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the other questions you've asked.  Looking at the big picture, I think the most important thing for you to know is that with multiples, there is a greater risk of losing the pregnancy or of having significantly premature babies.  I recommend the following: if twins happen along, do the best you can -- it can be stressful; but don't go looking for them.  Perhaps you could have a homemade baby and adopt a baby or small child if you want to speed things up a bit.